# Rgui - disable right click on plot window?

Tags: windows, r, rgui

I've written a routine whereby a user is displayed an image (using `grid.raster`) and they click on it to define a region of interest (`grid.locator`).

I added in support for the user to right-click on the plot instead of left-click, which would undo their previously-clicked point.

This works by testing whether `grid.locator()` returns `NULL` (from the help file:  "If the user did not click mouse button 1, the function (invisibly) returns `NULL`).

This works fine on Linux, but in Windows using Rgui, right-clicking the plot window brings up a context menu with 'Stop' and 'Continue' and continues waiting for you to click (i.e. the right click is not detected by `grid.locator()` since it's intercepted for the context menu first).

**Is there some way to disable the right click context menu for the plot window in Rgui?**

(The user is only going to use Rgui. For the moment I can tell them to use the middle click button to undo instead of right click and this works, but it is moot if they don't have a button with a scroll wheel/middle click button. Alternatively if there's some way I can listen for a keyboard event without having to load a UI package like gtk or tcltk I'm happy for that to happen too).

Comment: Not straight R, but a similar concept works for me:

Use AutoHotkey, check for active RGui Window, and Handle your right mouse button.